# How to get rid of ”TEKSAVVY DNS resolver”? (breaks NextDNS)

Tags: windows-10, dns, network-adapter, opendns

**TL;dr:**

How do I completely reset [NextDNS](https://nextdns.io/), to remove the mysterious "TEKSAVVY DNS Resolver"?

---

**Explanation:**

I'd been using [NextDNS](https://nextdns.io/) (Windows 10) for a while to block undesirable connections (such as Facebook's long arm online).  It stopped working, and I tried several things including reinstalling and doing a network reset.

So, I'm not sure at which point this changed, but checking the status at https://my.nextdns.io/ currently tells me:

> *This device is not using NextDNS.*
> ***This device is currently using ”TEKSAVVY” as DNS resolver.***

Wikipedia tells me [TekSavvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TekSavvy) is a Canadian "Telecommunications Provider" (who I never heard of before) which apparently *does* have ties to my DSL provider — but I assume this is irrelevant since I use NextDNS on other devices on the same network without an issue.

Several re-installs and resets haven't helped. The Network Troubleshooter finds no problems.

[image]

I noticed that when uninstalling NextDNS, or running the "Network Reset", neither actually removes the "NextDNS Tap-Windows adapter" showing in Network Connections (below), and it's `Delete` option is disabled. I'm not sure if that's relevant, but the Network Reset *did* remove/reinstall the other 2 adapters (for wifi and ethernet).

[image]

**Any thoughts as to what this "TEKSAVVY DNS Resolver" is, how to get rid of it, and/or how to *completely* reset NextDNS (including whatever connections/adapters it uses)?**

---

Some more info (nslookup on my own IP) based on troubleshooting I found [elsewhere](https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30150713-DNS-hijacking):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Turn off DNS over HTTPS in your browser network settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).